# Windows 8 Developer Preview - how to select between "Metro" IE and "Desktop" IE?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

I installed the Windows 8 Developer Preview. At some point, I needed IE in "Desktop" mode, (IE suggested to switch over based on the site). Now, whenever I launch IE from the Metro UI, it starts in desktop mode.

How do I get the Metro UI back ? Is it possible to create two shortcuts on the app screen, one for Metro and one for Desktop ?

Comment: If you pull the Search panel for Apps, how many "Internet Explorer" nodes do you find? What if you launch the IE tile listed there?

Comment: I have only one IE when searching.

Comment: If you search for Default programs, there are two IE programs, it isn't distinguishable of which one is the metro one but one of them is. I haven't got my installation on Win8 on hand to provide extra detail but it should be that way.

Comment: @sandeep funny i only see one IE entry in Default Programs.

Comment: If you've updated Windows 8 lately it could cause some problems, the recent updates literally destroyed my installation. I can't even use Visual Studio to work on updating my applications for Win8

Comment: Try set IE as the default program

Comment: Setting the default program for HTTP back to IE, worked. It seems for IE to work in Metro mode, it must be the default program (I hope this changes before release).

Comment: @driis - I am going to update the tag since I had a similar problem.  I assume the accepted answer works, I will need to restart my pc, but doing a complete system backup first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first try to reset internet explorer settings. It's also very likely the option you had access to isn't 100% complete and there may not be a stable or easy to find way to revert.

Get to the standard control panel window, and find internet settings, get to the advanced screen, there is a reset to defaults button there.

[image: internet explorer settings]

[image: control panel]

Worst case: reinstall a fresh copy of the developer preview.

Comment: i think using the new Control Panel > General settings, "Refresh your PC" or "Reset your PC" would have faster turnaround.